# Doesn't work stdout.write Method but can work stdout.writeln

Tags: dart, dart-io

```
import 'dart:io'
void main(){
stdout.write("abc");}
```

that code doesn't worked but

```
void main(){
stdout.writeln("abc");}
```

was work!! output is "abc" and

```
void main(){
stdout.write("abc");
stdout.writeln("def");}
```

out put is "abcdef"
I can't understand this happend...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `write` and `writeln` are non-blocking, with the difference that `writeln` is causing the buffer to be flushed. Your first code would work if you await a flush before ending your program:

```
import 'dart:io'

void main() async {
    stdout.write("abc");
    await stdout.flush();
}
```